# Image Button resizing

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imagebutton

I'm setting up an image button in Android Studio. All looks fine in design view, but when the application is loaded, the image button is moved to the top left corner and reduced in size?

Shown below:

Design View

[image]

XML Code - current

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.PhysicalActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnImageGallery"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:onClick="onImageGalleryClicked"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.921"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.74" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

PhysicalActivity Code

```
package com.example.futura.ui;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.futura.R;

import java.io.File;

public class PhysicalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST = 20;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_physical1);

    }

    public void onImageGalleryClicked(View v){


        // invoke the image gallery using an implict intent.
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

        File pictureDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        String pictureDirectoryPath = pictureDirectory.getPath();

        // finally, get ui represenation

        Uri data = Uri.parse(pictureDirectoryPath);

        // set the data and type, get all image types

        photoPickerIntent.setDataAndType(data, "image/*" );

        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, IMAGE_GALLERY_REQUEST);


    }

}
```

Preview

[image]

Does any one have any advice on correcting this?

Comment: intead using marginTop, you can use vertical bias. Also you didn't add any src to your image button

Comment: try removing  margin or you can set margin 0

Comment: when using constraints , don't provide the hardcoded height and width for **`imageButton`**.Let it span according to its constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add `layout_constraintHorizontal_bias` and `layout_constraintStart_toStartOf`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnImageGallery"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:onClick="onImageGalleryClicked"
        android:src="@drawable/placeholder"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.921"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.74" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for adding this. Still getting the same result shown in my original preview unfortunately.

Comment: how you inflate `activity_physical.xml` ? Please show us your java code for that part.

Comment: What do you mean? I use an intent to activate activity_physical. Would you like to see that code?

Comment: Show us your `PhysicalActivity.class`. I tested my code and it works fine

Comment: I see. Updated original post to include PhysicalActivity code.

Comment: Wow haha, sorry. Thank you for your time and help, I appreciate it! I'm going to pretend that didn't happen... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Remove margins (start, top, bottom, end) and adjust `layout_constraintHorizontal_bias`, `layout_constraintVertical_bias` to achieve desired result.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:id="@+id/startSyncButton"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.9"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.7"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I copied your code and matched up to my app id. Although, I still seem to be getting the same result shown in my preview image.

Comment: Ignore previous comment - I removed the margins, and adjusted those values. Still getting the same result unfortunately

Comment: What about activity_physical, activity_physical1, activity_physical2, activity_physical3, .....?

Comment: How many layouts do you have with that type of naming?
and which layout are you editing?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now sorted, you were absolutely right. Using the wrong layout like an idiot :)